# How to access application.yml properties in Spring 1.5.9

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, yaml, lombok

I'm spinning my wheels on this.

Here is a simple Spring Boot app.   I'm trying to use a yaml properties file, but I can't seem to get it to find the properties file or let me access the values in it.  I've tried many variations from advice I've searched for here and elsewhere.  Nothing is working.

(For reasons I can't go into, I have to use an older version of Spring. (1.5.9))

In IntelliJ I have the Lombok plugin installed, annotations enabled and the language is set to Java 1.8.

Here is the error I'm getting currently:

```
[ERROR] demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Foo.java:[9,10] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method value()
[ERROR] location: @interface lombok.Value
[ERROR] demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Foo.java:[9,3] annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
[ERROR] demo/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Foo.java:[13,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable log
[ERROR] location: class com.example.demo.Foo
```

Here is the folder structure:

[image]

Here is the application.yml file:

```
project:
  thing:
    path:  resources/foo_files
```

Here is the main class:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Foo foo = new Foo();

    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Here is class Foo:

```
package com.example.demo;

import lombok.Value;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
class Foo {

  @Value("${project.thing.path}")
  private String projectThingPath;

  public Foo() {
    log.info("path is: " + projectThingPath);
  }
}
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

For getting value from application.yml you should be using `@Value` from the package `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value` but you are using lombok's @Value

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value; // Changed
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Slf4j
@Component // EDIT : Added
class Foo {

  @Value("${project.thing.path}")
  private String projectThingPath;

  public Foo() {
    log.info("path is: " + projectThingPath);
  }
}
```

### EDIT

So another important point is that, a class should be annotated with stereotype annotation ( To tell Spring to configure the data).

Comment: That makes sense, thank you.  I wonder which maven package I need for that

Comment: It comes with `spring-boot-starter` so no need to add any other dependencies, you could just import it using `import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value`

Comment: When I run it though, it says "path is null"

Comment: is the property in application.yml same as `project.thing.path`

Comment: Yes, they are the same - the application.yml is listed above in the question.  I think the problem is that you can't access the properties until the SpringApplication has entered the "run" phase.  When I created the Foo class with "new", the value is null.  But if I access foo via the @Value annotation as you show, then it can be read. I would love to know if there is another way to get to them, but I haven't found it.

Comment: okay I have missed important point there, I will edit above ( you have to mention a stereotype annotation)

Comment: Even adding this, the path is null when Foo is created with new.  But ok

Comment: you should create a new instance instead you have to autowire the class and use that

Answer (score 1):

You have compile **error** because you are using **@Slf4j** (lombok annotation) but you have not *Slf4j* lib in your dependencies

In this case you can use **@Log** or add *Slf4j* to your dependencies

Comment: Slf4j is part of lombok which is included

Comment: no, lombock doesn't include, you can see in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok/1.18.8 (Compile Dependencies (0))

Comment: Hmm, when I click through on another working project with @Slf4j, it takes me to lombok-1.16.8 jar with the path: lombok.extern.slf4j?

Comment: lombok.extern.slf4j it's not Slf4j logger API it's just annotation lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j, lombol it's annotation post processor that provide the abilty to transform java source classes, and doesn't bring dependencies

Comment: @Avi is also right about org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value